# Consuming messages in Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I'm trying to create a consumer that reads the value of the message sent by the producer on Kafka. I've run the next code but it looks like the for loop doesn't work because my list is empty. Any ideas? Thank you!

```
data = []

consumer = KafkaConsumer('user',bootstrap_servers='yyy:0000',auto_offset_reset='smallest',consumer_timeout_ms = 10000)

for message in consumer:
    data.append(message.value)
```

Comment: Surely `yyy:0000` is not a real address? And is there actually data in the topic? And when are you printing the contents of the list or messages since that is an infinite loop?

Comment: aren't the 2 possible values for `auto_offset_reset`, `earliest` and `latest` (as in Java)? Are you running your consumer after you start up your producer? If so, you'd need to use the equivalent of `earliest`. I'd keep my consumer running and then produce a message.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Maybe the mistake is in producer part but I do not where: producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='****:****')
x = np.random.normal(loc = 0.1, scale = 0.05, size = 1000)
for i in range (1, 1000): 
    producer.send('myTopic',value=bytes(x))